# Tag ambiguity [mlab] and [mongolab]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

The tag [mlab](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mlab/info) is defined to point to the python-matlab bridge of that name. However many recent questions on that tag are actually related to the PaaS provider of that name [mlab](https://mlab.com). That company used to be called *mongolab*. There is already a tag for that [mongolab](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mongolab/info). The latter has more questions (483) than the former (200) but neither are particularly popular.

Should [mlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mlab) be renamed to [python-mlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-mlab) or [matlab-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-python) and [mongolab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongolab) then be renamed to [mlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mlab)?

Answer (score 6):

I don't particularly care for tacking on language tags to a tag unless absolutely necessary. Irritatingly, it *shouldn't* have been necessary: the mlab library is based on the older mlabwrap library [which already has its own tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mlabwrap).

Oh well. It gets even worse: most of the python questions in the mlab tag aren't even about the python-matlab bridge; they're about the [Mayavi MLab API](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_reference.html#mlab-reference) or the [matplotlib.mlab API](https://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html). Those, at least, I don't feel so bad about namespacing.

So here's what I've done:

- The questions that were obviously about Mayavi I retagged [mayavi.mlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mayavi.mlab)
- The questions that were obviously about Matplotlib I retagged [matplotlib.mlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matplotlib.mlab)
- The questions that appeared to be about the bridge library I retagged [python-mlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-mlab)

I then retagged the rest to mongolab, and finished by renaming mongolab ->
 [mlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mlab) (with a synonym in place). These should *mostly* be about the same thing, so I think we're good.